# How to have a dictionary filter in QML

Tags: listview, qml, qlistview

When you go to Contacts on your iPhone there is an indexing list on the right containing alphabets from A to #. It is clickable and you can slide on it. I want to have something similar in my project but there is nothing that I could find how to achieve it. Can somebody please guide me.

I did some more research regarding how to accomplish this task. Below is the code that I am using.

```
    ListView{
        id: cView
        width: 300
        height: 300
        model: CModel{}
        clip: true
        delegate: cDelegate
        visible: false
        section {
            property: "name"
            criteria: ViewSection.FirstCharacter
        }
        ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {
            id: scrollBar
            Rectangle {
                id: bigRect
                visible: scrollBar.pressed
                color: "#1976D2"
                width: 96
                height: width
                radius: width/2
                x: -width - 16
                y: Math.max(scrollBar.position * scrollBar.height - height, 0)  // Not so sure about this formula yet.
                z:4
                Rectangle {
                    width: parent.width/2
                    height: parent.height/2
                    x: width
                    y: height
                    color: parent.color
                }
                Label {
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                    color: "White"
                    font.bold: true
                    font.pixelSize: 40
                    property Item topItem: cView.itemAt(0, cView.contentY)
                    property Item topItemFix: topItem ? topItem: cView.contentItem.children[0]
                    text: topItemFix.ListView.section
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

The CModel{} is a separate QML file which I am using for Model Data. Every ListElement has just name associated with it.

And the cDelegate is for the ListView which works fine too... I am having one issue with this code.. When I scroll Down the ScrollBar, the text inside the bigRect is not changing.. It just displays "A". Upon Scrolling also this text does not change.. It has to be something to do with the last statement text: topItemFix.ListView.section but I am not able to see anything.

Although this is not exactly what I want to do.. But after this is complete then I can work towards the final thing.

Below is the code for cDelegate.

```
    Component{
        id: cDelegate
        Rectangle{
            id: anItemz
            width: ListView.view.width
            color: "#f8f8f8"
            height: 74
            x: 70
            y: 90

            Text {
                text: name
                x:24
                y:20
                width: 199
                height: 40
                font.family: 'Helvetica Neue'
                font.pixelSize: 28
            }
    }
```

}

The CModel.qml file looks like this---------

```
import QtQuick 2.10
import QtQuick.Window 2.10

ListModel{
    id: contacts
ListElement{
    name: "abc"
}
ListElement{
    name: "def"
}
.
.
.
.
.
}
```

Comment: First you need to decide whether you want to use `qml` or `qlistview` - and then you need to implement this your self, since yes - it is not there as a ready to use building block. If you fail somewhere, show the code that you have tried, and we try to help you. **Hint:** you can analyze the data in the model to find the indices you are looking for.

Comment: I have updated the code above.. Please check.

Comment: Hi, I would like to try your example, but since it is not complete I fail. I can easily create a `ListModel` with some dummy data for `CModel` if I'd know the structure. I fail with `CDelegate` and `contactView`. Please make sure that I can run your example without first understanding where I might need to build additional stuff. Provide everything that is necessary, and strip, what is not needed to illustrate your problem.

Comment: @derM I have updated the code so now you should be able to try it. Thanks for your help.